# How to delete interaction.channel.send message

Tags: node.js, function, discord, discord.js, es6-modules

I have a function to delete a message after I send it:

```js
export function del(interaction) {
  setTimeout(() => interaction.deleteReply(), 1000);
}
```

I want to convert it so this will be working to `interaction.channel.send`, earlier I used `interaction.reply()`, but I don't want my bot to continue using reply to every command. I read Discord docs and didn't find anything helpful.

Any help on how to do this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `interaction.channel.send` you need to track the new message that you created (as it separate from the interaction).

Here is a quick sample where I have /ping command that creates and deletes a reply and a message:

```js
module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("ping")
    .setDescription("Replies with Pong!"),
  async execute(interaction) {
    await interaction.reply("Pong!");
    const msg = await interaction.channel.send("Pong! 2!");

    //Delete reply
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await interaction.deleteReply();
    }, 1000);

    //delete message
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await msg.delete();
    }, 1500);
  },
};
```